# How to free calloc memory inside a char * function?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I have a function `char *getArg1(char *input)`, this function returns only the first argument of the input string. It callocs space for arg1 within the function and I can't seem to correctly free this memory from the place where I call the function

```
char *arg1 = calloc(end - start + 1, sizeof(char));
for (int j = start; j < end; j++)
{
    arg1[j - start] = input[j];
}
arg1[end - start] = '\0';

return arg1;
```

This is the code withing the `char *getArg1(char *input)` function that allocates the memory. I thought it was a simple as calling free after calling this function for instance:

```
char *boolfuncInput = getArg1(input);
....
free(boolfuncInput);
```

Comment: This error i produced when i do the above: AddressSanitizer: attempting free on address which was not malloc()-ed: 0x602000000031 in thread T0

Comment: Please [edit] your post and make at least a compilable function and indicate where `start` and `end` are coming from. Also the calling code would be useful to see if you are overwriting `boolfuncInput` elsewhere. Finally, please add the error information to the post, not as a comment where people may overlook it.

Comment: OT: Will the "first argument" ever be more than, say, 100 characters? If not, then you could simply allocate a buffer of 100 + 1 bytes, copy into it, and release it when you're done.  There's nothing but heartache in trying to fondle each byte over and over and "use the absolute minimum amount of heap."... `calloc()`, `strchr()` and `memcpy()` would turn this (and what's not shown) into a function of 3-4 lines...

Comment: You question, as it's currently written, contains an incomplete code snippet that cannot be easily compiled and tested by others, which makes it impossible for us to tell you why the error is happening. Edit the question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Add a condition to check the return value of `calloc`. Double check that `boolfuncInput` is not modified anywhere else before `free`.

Comment: Before fussing about ```free```, check the return value of ```calloc``` to see if the memory was even allocated successfully.

Comment: Seems to work: https://godbolt.org/z/fxrTPhhee